# KDB indexing a matrix

Tags: kdb

I have two matrices:

```
a: (0.5 0.5; 0.3 0.7)
idx: ((0 0);(0 1);(1 1))
```

I want to use the idx as `i` and `j` pairs to get the values out of `a`. In longform, this would be:

```
a[0;0]
a[0;1]
a[1;1]
```

Currently, when I try to index it as `a idx`, it behaves as if I've entered `a[0 0]` etc.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to use `.` index with each right `/:` here:

```
a ./:idx
```

Comment: [Index](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/apply/#index)

Comment: [Each Right](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/maps/#each-left-and-each-right)

Answer (score 1):

Apply Each Right (@kylebonnes) is the correct answer to OP. You might prefer an alternative approach to scattered indexing if it suited you better to represent `a` as a vector.

```
q)M:2 2#V:5 5 3 7%10  / matrix; vector
q)r:0 0 1;c:0 1 1     / rows; columns

q)M ./:r,'c
0.5 0.5 0.7

q)V 0 2 sv(r;c)       / index V as if it were M
0.5 0.5 0.7
```

Here the left argument  [`sv`](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/sv/) specifies a (variable) arithmetic base. For rows `r` and columns `c` you can use `(0,N)sv(r;c)` as indexes into a razed N-column matrix.

```
q)show A:4 5#B:"the  quickbrownfox  "
"the  "
"quick"
"brown"
"fox  "
q)rc:6 2#2 0 2 1 1 1 2 4 1 3 0 1
q)A ./: rc
"brunch"
q)B 0 5 sv flip rc
"brunch"
```